# GIT: How Do I Revert All The Changes Of One Branch From Another Branch

Tags: git, git-revert

In git, how do i revert all the changes of one branch from another branch.

I have previously branched from the `master` branch to a branch called `feature/new-feature`

While working on my feature other people also worked from the `master` branch and many were merged back into `master` (including mine).

Suppose i want to remove all the changed i made on `feature/my-feature` from the master branch. What git command would i need to use to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I assume things were merged, and not rebased.

run a `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` to get a pretty graph of your history. Find the commit hash of the merge where your branch was merged into master.

You'll want to do a `git revert`. However, as this is a merge, you'll need to choose one of the two parent commits for this commit. You can tag on a `-m 1` to indicate that the parent commit to choose is the commit from the branch that was merged into (master). Run `git revert -m 1 <merge commit hash>`, and resolve any conflicts.

This will appear as a single commit, and can be re-`revert`ed/`reset` at a later point if done incorrectly.

Comment: thanks. but i have merged multiple times. is there a way to specify a branch instead of a commit hash? or is there another way around this other than reverting all the merge commits one at a time?

Comment: @X0r0N Afaik, branches aren't reflected in the history outside of the default merge commit descriptions. Reverting the commits one by one is probably your best bet.

Comment: Command to get commit IDs: `git log --all --pretty=format:"%h" --merges --grep "Merge.*feature/my-feature'.*into master"`. If you use GitHub: `git log --all --pretty=format:"%h" --merges --grep "Merge pull request .* from .*feature/my-feature`. Then you can pipe it to `xargs git revert -m1` but there may be conflicts.